# Extracting text from a string using regular expressions

Tags: python, regex

I need to extract text from strings using regular expressions. Examples:

```
//localhost:8000/pmp/pml/vault/
//localhost:8000/pmp/bom/vault/
//localhost:8000/pmp/parts/advancedsearch/
```

The string may be a different localhost number or the front half may be a different address altogether. I need to extract from `/pmp/` to the following slash. So:

```
/pmp/pml/
/pmp/bom/
/pmp/parts/
```

What is the regular expression I could use to extract that text. Also please provide details for what each component of the regular expression is doing as I am trying to learn this rather than just get the answer.

I have the following bit of regex, but it only works for when the string is split after the localhost number. Also, I don't know what any part of it means:

`/[^/]*/([^/]*)/`

Comment: https://regex101.com/ provies both references and explanations if you're trying to learn. Don't forget to swithc to python in the flavour selection on the left side.

Comment: Why do you need to use Regex for that?

Answer (score 3):

You don't need Regex for everything. Regex are hard to understand, hard to maintain and there are better solutions for many things.

```py
from urllib.parse import urlparse
print(urlparse("//localhost:8000/pmp/parts/advancedsearch/"))
```

This code makes it clear for everyone that you are parsing an URL. The Regex doesn't convey this message.

Output:

```
ParseResult(scheme='', netloc='localhost:8000', path='/pmp/parts/advancedsearch/', params='', query='', fragment='')
```

As you can see, `path` is what you want to process next, e.g.

```py
from urllib.parse import urlparse
url = urlparse("//localhost:8000/pmp/parts/advancedsearch/")
dirs = url.path.split("/")
print(f"/{dirs[1]}/{dirs[2]}/")
```

Answer (score 2):

This skips over the hostname + portnumber,
and captures whatever `/pmp/someword/` immediately follows that.

```
import re

pmp_re = re.compile(r"^//localhost:\d+(/pmp/\w+/)")
if match := pmp_re.search(url):
    print(match[1])
```

The `^` carat anchor forces any match to begin at the beginning,
and the `(` `)` parens define matching group #1.
When looking for a `\d`igit or `\w`ord character,
the `+` insists on one-or-more matches.

https://regex101.com/r/KsOaBQ/1

This regex is fragile, as port `80` might come out as `localhost:80/`
or just `localhost/`.
We *could* make the colon and digits optional
using `?` for zero-or-one and `*` for zero-or-more matches:

```
pmp_re = re.compile(r"^//localhost:?\d*(/pmp/\w+/)")
```

But it would be better to call
[urlparse()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#url-parsing)
and then work with the `path` it returns.

When we study the last part of that regex, `/\w+/`,
it's worth noting that `/` slash is not a `\w`ord character;
it is neither alphanumeric nor `_` underscore.
We *could* use a fancy "[not](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) slash" regex of `/[^/]+/`,
but that would be much less readable,
so I recommend that if possible you should avoid
going down that path.
Humans can more easily read things stated in the positive
than in the negative.
There are also fancy "[lazy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301285/what-do-lazy-and-greedy-mean-in-the-context-of-regular-expressions)" modifiers like `/.+?/`
that one might use, but again that won't improve
the code's readability for a novice.

Answer (score 1):

You can slightly adjust your *regex* attempt from `/[^/]*/([^/]*)/` to `//[^/]+(/[^/]+/[^/]+/).*`.

- `//` : Matches literal double slashes at the start
- `[^/]+` : Matches any sequence of characters (*different than a slash*)
- `(/[^/]+/[^/]+/)` : Matches the desired portion/path enclosed and making a group
- `.*` : Matches any sequence of characters (*zero or more*)

> Regex : [[*demo*](https://regex101.com/r/UrOIWH/1)]

Test/Output :

```
import re

list_of_urls = [
    "//localhost:8000/foo/pml/vault/",
    "//localhost:8000/bar/bom/vault/",
    "//localhost:8000/baz/parts/advancedsearch/",
]

def get_path(url):
    m = re.search(r"//[^/]+(/[^/]+/[^/]+/).*", url)
    return m.group(1) if m else None
```

---

```
for url in list_of_urls:
    print(get_path(url))

/foo/pml/
/bar/bom/
/baz/parts/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following.

```
(/pmp/.+?/)
```

The parentheses denote a capture group.

The . character will match any character.
The subsequent + is a *quantifier*, which will attempt to match one or more of the preceded element.
And, the ? is a modifier, to the quantifier, specifying that it should match as little as possible, as opposed the as much as possible—the default.